# How to start a activity from cardview. I'm trying to start other fragmentActivity from my CardViewHolder class but app is crashing

Tags: android, android-cardview

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

public TextView countryName;
public ImageView countryPhoto;
public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    countryName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cardTitle);
    countryPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_cardImages);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked Country Position = " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

Comment: where is your `Intent`

Comment: Show your error log.

Comment: Where calling `startActivity` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreateView()` method in RecyclerView's Adapter Class, you need to get a reference to your card or whatever it is that you want to click on and you also need to pass `Context` variable when attaching your Adapter to your `RecyclerView`.

Finally, write a method in your Activity like this:

```
public void openAnotherActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And in your Adapter :

```
whateverItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        ((Activity)context).openAnotherActivity();
                    }
                });
```